# Solr: data import handler doesn't import dynamic fields from xml

Tags: xml, dynamic, solr, rss, dih

I am trying to import an xml into solr 5.3 but it doesn't import dynamic fields defined in schema.xml

[xml file]

```
<rss>
    <doc>
        <id>1120265</id>
        <name_s>Alfa Romeo version</name_s>
        <status>15</status>
        <color_s>White</color_s>
        <price_f>16900</price_f>
    </doc>
</rss>
```

[dataimport-config-xml]

```
    <dataConfig>    
    <!-- devel -->
    <dataSource type="URLDataSource" />

    <document name="clasificados">
        <entity name="clasificado" processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
                rootEntity="rss"
                url="http://dev.admin.clasificados.com/solr.xml" stream="true"
                forEach="/rss/doc">
            <field column="id" xpath="/rss/doc/id" />
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

I added the 'id' field and it's imported fine.

I tried the useSolrAddSchema param but didn't work.

The dynamic fields appear in the schema browser in the solr backend.

Answer (score 1):

According to Solr Docs if you want to use **useSolrAddSchema** then the content has to be in the form of the standard Solr update XML schema.
[XML File]

```
<add>
    <doc>
        <field name="id">1120265</field>
        <field name="name_s">Alfa Romeo version</field>
        <field name="status">15</field>
        <field name="color_s">White</field>
        <field name="price_f">16900</field>
    </doc>
</add>
```

[dataimport-config-xml]

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="URLDataSource" />
    <document>
        <entity name="clasificado" processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
                url="http://dev.admin.clasificados.com/solr.xml" stream="true"
                useSolrAddSchema="true">
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Now if you run DIH then all the dynamic fields will get indexed.

Comment: Are you sure that your input XML is in required Format?